# Why is malloc called on two different pointers the same address space?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, heap-corruption

The code below comes from a homework assignment discussing heap-overflow exploitations, which I understand as a concept. What I don't understand is what is going on exactly with malloc and the pointers in this code example. Obviously both pointers are pointing to the same space in the heap, but why is this? Wouldn't malloc reserve the space for `buf1` and then reserve *another* space for `buf2`?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int diff, size = 8;
    char *buf1, *buf2;
    buf1 = (char * )malloc(size);
    buf2 = (char *)malloc(size);
    diff = buf2-buf1;
    memset(buf2, '2', size);
    printf("BEFORE: buf2 = %s",buf2);
    memset(buf1, '1', diff +3);
    printf("AFTER: buf2 = %s", buf2);
    return 0;
}
```

This code produces the output

```
BEFORE: buf2 = 22222222AFTER: buf2 = 11122222
```

Many thanks. :)

Comment: How did this not AV/segfault?  The miracles of UB:)

Comment: There is quit a bit wrong with this code. 1. You're not passing null terminated strings to `printf`. 2. You're assuming that some reliable relationship between the address of the two pointers exists.  3. Don't cast the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: Why do you think buf1 and buf2 are pointing to the same space? If they were, then they'd be equal, and diff would be 0. Is diff 0? Unlikely. (BTW, argv shouldn't be const and buf2 *should* be null-terminated.)

Comment: @MartinJames: Yeah...

Comment: "Obviously both pointers are pointing to the same space in the heap" - they're pointing to the "same space in the heap" insofar as they're both pointing to the same heap, but they're not pointing to the same location within it. What gave you that idea?

Comment: @EdS. Assuming some relationship between the pointer addresses is reasonable in an exploit. They aren't usually standards conformant!

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, why does the result of modifying buf1 show up when printing bf2 on the second printf?

Comment: @jmeanor: Because the first `malloc()` call allocates 8 bytes for you, and the second `malloc()` call allocates the *next* 8 bytes. When you overwrite the bounds of the first allocation, you just plough straight through and starting writing into the second allocation. It's not guaranteed that you'll always get contiguous allocations like this, but if you're allocating block sizes that are divisible by alignment requirements, you can probably expect a sane memory allocator to do this.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, thanks! I get it now, I assumed that dif was resulting to 0, but it's really 8. It's been a long semester. :o)

Comment: `buf1` and `buf2` point to two distinct objects. Subtracting the two pointers has undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: You **cannot** "expect" contiguous allocations outside of a trivial example. Allocate blocks A and B, and release block A. Now allocate two blocks, and all bets are off whether you get C and D (contiguous) or A and C (non-contiguous). Add multithreading to the mix, and you'll see why you shouldn't assume anything about the behaviour of any memory allocator you haven't implemented yourself (and really, even *if* you implemented it yourself). Hands off of UB.

Comment: @DevSolar: Nothing is being released and there is there no multithreading, here. Perhaps you're thinking of someone else.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: We are clearly looking at a minimal working *example* here. I consider it bordercase careless to say something like, quote, "if you're allocating block sizes that are divisible by alignment requirements, you can probably expect a sane memory allocator to do this", end quote, and not consider that people might take this statement and apply it to a non-trivial environment. I much prefer *not* having to hunt down the resulting mess of race conditions in a multithreaded application one day.

Comment: @DevSolar: "Do this" means "do what happened in the case of this here program in the question", and under the specified circumstances, you certainly can "expect a sane memory allocator to do this", as we have seen. Is it guaranteed to? No. But you can expect it to, and a lot of the time, you'll be right to expect it. Whether or not you can expect it to is completely unrelated to the question of whether you should write programs that rely on it, which is something nobody but you has suggested. The issue at hand is to explain the behavior in the question, nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Explanation of the result**

`buf1` and `buf2` are not pointing to the same space.

Your result can be explained as follows.

By luck the allocations gives the following memory layout:

```
buf1      buf2 
|--------|--------|
```

The first memset gives

```
buf1      buf2 
|--------|22222222|
```

as in it sets from the start of buf2 to the end to 2.

The second memset gives:

```
buf1      buf2 
|11111111|11122222|
```

That is it sets from the start of `buf1` to 3 past it's end.

**Undefined behaviour**

This does not seg fault as you are changing memory that is allocated to your program.

However passing `buf2` to `printf` in that way is invoking undefined behavior.

The reason is that `printf` involked as:

```
printf("BEFORE: buf2 = %s",buf2);
```

does not have a way to know the size of `buf2` so it continues until it sees the null value `\0` character which your code does not add. It seems by luck you got the value immediately after buf2 happens the be the null value.

You could either add the `\0` character to the end of `buf2`.

Or maybe more fitting in this case you could usethe precision format specifier (that's a `.` folowed by an `int` value) to let `printf` know how many characters to print. That would be done as so:

```
printf("BEFORE: buf2 = %.8s",buf2);
```

Comment: The visual explains it. Makes perfect sense now, thanks a bunch!

Comment: I expected a segfault 'cos the unterminated string dumps.

Comment: @MartinJames aha I see what you mean. Thanks for pointing that out! I've updated the answer to explain that also.